# Trying to write a function that simulates a single t-statistic from two samples

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

I am trying to write my own function that simulates a t-stat from two samples of equal size.

```
cntrl <- c(8.4,8.1,5.1,7.6,4.7,10.7,5.7,4.1,8.1,6.8)
strv <- c(12.4,15.8,11.7,8.6,12.6,11.1,10.5,7.3,7.2,10.8)
```

I put the cntrl into the sample but where do I put strv?

```
single_rt <- function(size1, size2) {x1 <-sample(x=cntrl, size =size1, replace = TRUE) (mean(x1)-mean(x2))/sqrt((var(x1)/size2) +(var(x2)/size1))}

my_rt <- function(n, size1, size2) {replicate(n=n, expr = single_rt(size1=size1, size2 = size2))}

num_reps <- 10000; N1 <-10; N2 <- 10

t.stats <-my_rt(n=num_reps, size1 = N1, size2 = N2)
```

I get this error code

> Error in sample(x = cntrl, size = size1, replace = TRUE)(mean(x1) -
>   mean(x2)) :    attempt to apply non-function

Comment: You need to put the part of the first function starting at `(mean(x1)...` on a new line, or add a semicolon before it

Comment: I did that and it worked, but where do i put my other vector?

Comment: > single_rt <- function(size1, size2) {x1 <- rnorm(x=cntrl, n=10);x2 <-rnorm(strv, n=10); (mean(x1)-mean(x2))/sqrt((var(x1)/size2) +(var(x2)/size1))}
> t.stats <-my_rt(n=num_reps, size1 = N1, size2 = N2)
 
 Error in rnorm(x = cntrl, n = 10) : unused argument (x = cntrl)

Comment: The answer behind gives you a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with `rnorm` ?

One possibility is :

```
single_rt <- function(size1, size2){
  x1 <- rnorm(n = size1)
  x2 <- rnorm(n = size2)
  return((mean(x1)-mean(x2))/sqrt((var(x1)/size2) + (var(x2)/size1)))}

my_rt <- function(n, size1, size2, x1, x2){
  replicate(n=n, expr = single_rt(size1=size1, size2 = size2))}
num_reps <- 10000
N1 <- 10
N2 <- 10

t.stats <-my_rt(n=num_reps, size1 = N1, size2 = N2)
```

If you look closely at the `rnorm` function it takes 3 arguments and not a vector. If you want to perturbate your sample with noise, you should do differently.

If you want to use the `sample` function which I advise you, the code below is the one you should use :

```
single_rt_bis <- function(size1, size2, x1 = x1, x2 = x2){
  x1 <- sample(x=x1, size = size1, replace = TRUE)
  x2 <- sample(x=x2, size = size2, replace = TRUE)
  return((mean(x1)-mean(x2))/sqrt((var(x1)/size2) + (var(x2)/size1)))}


my_rt <- function(n, size1, size2, x1, x2){
  replicate(n = n, expr = single_rt_bis(size1 = size1, size2 = size2, x1 = x1, x2 = x2))}

num_reps <- 10000
N1 <- 10
N2 <- 10

t.stats <-my_rt(n = num_reps, size1 = N1, size2 = N2, x1 = cntrl, x2 = strv)
```

In fact, what you want to do seems to use boostrap to simulate different t-test with the same sample. The code above do exactly that.